# Does `resize2fs` only move the end position of a filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, gparted, resize2fs

`man resize2fs` says

> The size parameter specifies the requested new size of the filesystem.

Does `resize2fs` only move the end position of a filesystem, not the beginning position of a filesystem (even if the filesystem  start a distance away from the beginning of the underlying partition),  similarly to `parted resize`?

gparted use `resize2fs` to resize a filesystem. How can gparted move the beginning position of a filesystem then?

Comment: Yes. gparted can not only resize filesystem but also move a filesystem. which is much like a memmove()

Comment: I am mainly asking about resize2fs

Comment: Then I just said yes. It doesn't change the starting storage address but will change the end address. But shrinking a filesystem actually needs to overwriting important parts of the data structure (usually some metadata in the head), not only simply cutting the tail off.